USB-C device doesn't work
I made a USB device based on STM32 blue pill board (STM32F103C8T6) having USB-C female socket. It works well when connected via a type C to type C cable. The Blue Pill board itself doesn't have any resistors on CC1/CC2 USB pins, but the cable I use has a 1k resistor internally on CC1, so my device gets 5 V from the computer.
Now I'm trying to get the USB negotiation working on my own PCB, which has a USB male connector. The idea is to plug it directly into a laptop without any cables. I have a 1k resistor on CC1 and 5k on CC2, not sure if that's correct, but at least I can get 5 V supply from any device.
Now, the problem is that nothing happens when I plug my device into the laptop. I expect at least a message in system logs like usb 3-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd, but it says nothing at all. I tried replacing the microcontroller, but with no luck. How to make USB male plug device be recognized properly by a computer? Is such a mode even supported?
All connections are checked multiple times. D+/D- lines are connected through 22 ohms resistors as on Blue Pill.



Is there any USB firmware programmed in the STM32F103C8T6 on the custom board?

What do you expect to happen? Have you uploaded some USB firmware to STM32? Where is the schematics to see if the wires are correct? And no, there should be no 1K resistor in your CC pin. And the 22 ohm series resistors are incorrect too. Do you have the required 1k5  pull-up on DP? Is it a good idea to plug unknown and weird stuff that might do damage to your expensive laptop?

Thank you @Justme! I added a 1.5k pull-up to D+ and now everything works!! The schematic/device photo are attached.

Almost all the components are taken from the Blue Pull dev board, and MCU with the working firmware as well. I also tested all electrical connections to ensure safety before plugging in into the laptop.

Both CC1 and CC2 pulldown resistors must be 5.1k.

Per Application note AN4879 for STM32 family,  "The USB FS impedance driver is always managed internally to avoid the need to add external serial resistors on the data line path" , see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/705615/117785 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/599061/117785

A small update. I made a new device (the previous one has lost, thanks to my cats). It didn't work with CC1/CC2 pulldown 5.1k, D+ pullup 1.5k. I was wondering why and finally found you need only one 5.1k resistor, doesn't matter CC1 or CC2. Otherwise devices such laptops don't output it 5V power.
I think the previois device worked by occasion because one of CC1/CC2 lines with two 5.1k resistors was actually broken.

The schematics had a missing pull-up for detection.
Pulling it up to 5V VBUS is wrong though. It needs to be pulled to 3.3V so nothing damages.

This is the schema I finally use for the working device. I mostly copied the BluePill schematic and reused components from it. Hopefully it would be helpful for someone. The usb-c stick works with Lenovo and Mac laptops well.
Someone's also said that R5/R10 are not needed. Most likely yes as I can see, but those 22-Ohm resistors were in BluePill so I left them.
List of differences from BluePill include

usb-female replaced with usb-male
added two buttons
added one more LED to pin 2



It's still wrong like I said in my answer. The pull-up on USB must not be to VBUS like the datasheet says. And STM32 USB internal PHYs do have USB compliant output impedance so series resistors are not needed. The reset pin is not recommended to have a pull-up. The capacitance on VBUS exceeds 10uF. The Blue Pill is a poor and bad example and should not be copied. Always believe MCU manufacturer documentation and examples.
